# Page breaks from word document not in kdp preview

Tags: kdp

I've uploaded my docx to KDP.

I have a page break before each 'heading 2' set in styles.

Through the book page breaks are honored...

except in Section 3.

Each section has 12 chapters.

6, 7, 8, 10, 11, and 12 do not break before the heading.

All others (including chapter 9) break before the heading.

Comment: Try to 'remove' the styling and re-apply the desired styling settings (in your .docx or in KDP kindle create) for those few particular spots where it fails to export properly. Without seeing actual CSS/HTML code, suggested solutions are limited. Welcome to ESE.